# Taxonomy as exposed Filter -> showing extra Field

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a taxonomy with german umlauts in terms. This taxonomy I use as exposed filter in a view (with [better exposed filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)). To work with views arguments I named the terms WITHOUT umlauts (Oesterreich for Österreich). And I have an extra field where I have the names WITH umlauts.

Now I want to get the values of these fields shown in exposed filters to have the correct spelling.

Does anyone know how I can get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution:

With [views reference filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) I created a view with taxonomy terms. I added the field WITH umlauts and added this view as filter in my actual view: taxonomy term (referenced). In the next step I selected the refernce filter view.

Comment: Can you tell me if you were able to, on results page, display for each filter result with their list of terms_WITH ?   I'm getting the termID as commma seprated list, but can't get the extra field the same. It keeps splitting the grouping and giving a result for each 'terms_WITH' per item instead of just swapping the tags for the 'preferred name'.

Comment: I think you need a relationship to the taxonomy. In my case I needed the filters for file entities so I additionally needed https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index.